# Detectar quando valor input é alterado via js

Tags: javascript

Tenho sistema terceiro que preenche um campo através de um zoom. Abaixo desse zoom tenho um grid de produtos (meu especifico). Preciso incluir um produto nesse grid sempre que o sistema preenche esse campo de produto. Entretanto, não existe um ponto de customização que possa interceptar o momento em que o produto é selecionado no zoom.

A questão é: Como detectar que o valor do campo foi alterado (lembrando que esse é alterado via javascript)? Já tentei utilizando os eventos: `bind` e `on` do **jquery** sem sucesso. Outra alternativa gambiarrenta foi usar um `settimeout`. Por enquanto estou buscando um saída mais elegante para solucionar tal situação.

Alguém já passou por algo parecido?

Comment: Podes usar o evento `change`, se é que percebo bem o teu problema. Podes colocar o HTML desse(s) campo(s)? Um exemplo live no jsFiddle seria ideal para perceber melhor.

Comment: Tentei usar o evento change. Entretanto, como o campo é alterado via js e nao pelo usuário ao que parece é ignorado

Comment: E o código JS que muda o valor não é teu?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/emirdeliz/26v6urLw/

Comment: Não é. Um sistema terceiro é responsável por abrir o zoom e setar o valor. Digamos que estou customizando um fragmento do sistema

Comment: E o sistema terceiro corre na tua página? Esse código está exposto ao espaço global? podias mudar o método deles que aplica a mudança de valor... meio bruto, mas senão acho que é mesmo o `setTimeout`... Algo assim: http://jsfiddle.net/26v6urLw/4/

Comment: Testei o códgio enviado pelo @Sergio e foi, inclusive adicionei uma função que altera o código no click e disparou o evento... veja [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/ycv54bhp/)

Answer (score 2):

Isso pode ser possivel no futuro. Está previsto um novo método que pode resolver esse problema, o [Object.observe()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe), prometido para ES7.

Se fôr para avante podes passar um objeto ao método e uma callback que será chamada por cada vez que houver uma alteração a propriedades do objeto. No teu caso deverá ser chamado com o evento `update`.

Porem isso ainda não existe e um dos [polyfillque já existe](https://github.com/MaxArt2501/object-observe) não funciona neste caso (http://jsfiddle.net/5ehaor1d/).

Assim restam duas possibilidades. Uma delas já te ocorreu também que é usar *setInterval* ou *setTimeout*.

A outra, é meio força bruta, e funciona caso o código externo use jQuery. A ideia consiste em alterar o método `.val()` do jQuery para disparar eventos quando mudar valores. Não garanto que não dê asneira mas neste caso funciona (http://jsfiddle.net/26v6urLw/4/).

```
var jVal = $.fn.val;
$.fn.val = function(v) {
    if (typeof v != 'undefined') jVal.call(this, v);
    else return jVal.call(this);
    if (v) $(this).trigger('change');
}
```

Comment: Tem uma solução interessante no SOen também: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19378549

Comment: @bfavaretto essa ideia é muito boa! Coloca uma resposta com ela.

Answer (score 0):

Se você pode modificar a função que altera o valor do campo, acredito que o problema é facilmente resolvido adicionando a linha `$("#teste").trigger('change');` logo abaixo da linha que modifica o valor do campo.
Assim sempre que o valor for modificado o evento `change` será disparado e o `handler` do evento irá capturá-lo e tratá-lo.

Comment: Entendi que ele não teria como alterar esse trecho do código (estaria fora do controle dele).

Comment: Se ele não tiver como alterar o trecho de código esta resposta não é válida, ai ele deve utilizar outra abordagem. Porém se ele tiver essa possibilidade é uma possível solução. Pelo que eu entendi ele teria acesso para realizar esta pequena modificação.

Comment: Realmente eu posso estar enganado.

Comment: Realmente eu não tenho acesso ao callback do zoom. Portando, não tem como interceptar

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo apoio. A opção que estou foi usar o setInterval. Mesmo não sendo a opção mais elegante o código não ficou tão ruim. Utilizei o seguinte link: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/monitoring-dom-properties/

Answer (score 0):

Muito obrigado pelo apoio. A opção que estou foi usar o setInterval. Mesmo não sendo a opção mais elegante o código não ficou tão ruim. Utilizei o seguinte link: [james.padolsey.com/javascript/monitoring-dom-properties](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/monitoring-dom-properties)